# Normalize all rows with first element within group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Is there an elegant method to normalize a column with a group-specific norm with dplyr?

Example:
I have a data frame:

```
df = data.frame(year=c(1:2, 1:2),
                group=c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                val=c(100, 200, 300, 900))
```

i.e:

```
  year group val
1    1     a 100
2    2     a 200
3    1     b 300
4    2     b 900
```

I want to normalize `val` by the value in year=1 of the given group. Desired output:

```
   year group val val_norm
1    1     a 100        1
2    2     a 200        2
3    1     b 300        1
4    2     b 900        3
```

e.g. in row 4 the norm = 300 (year==1 & group=="b") hence val_norm = 900/300 = 3.

I can achieve this by extracting a ancillary data frame with just norms and then doing a left join on the original data frame.

What is a more elegant way to achieve this without creating a temporary data frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can group by 'group', then divide the 'val' by the 'val' where 'year' is 1 (`year==1`).  Here, I am selecting the first observation (in case there are duplicate 'year' of 1 for each 'group').

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(val_norm = val/val[year==1][1L])
#      year  group   val val_norm
#  <int> <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1      a   100        1
#2     2      a   200        2
#3     1      b   300        1
#4     2      b   900        3
```

---

If we need elegance and efficiency, `data.table` can be tried

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, val_norm := val/val[year==1][1L] , by = group]
```

Comment: Excellent. I didn't know one can do subselects inside mutate ([year==1]). This is great. Thank you also for the data.table bonus.

Comment: @donlelek  You are right in this example, but it may fail if the `year` is not ordered.